# Access permission /opt/ in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

I want to access my /opt/ folder. I have found the following commands for giving access permission.

I am not sure what is the purpose of this commands, which one is the better to use it to maintain security and access permission both.

I want to understand the number system within this command.

`sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/`

`sudo chmod 755 /opt/`

`sudo chmod 775 /opt/`

`sudo chmod 777 /opt/`

I didn't know these commands, so what I use to do previously was `gksudo nautilius` then:

Right click > change the owner from root to current user group

Now I have found the `chmod` command I would like to better understand how this command works and how best to implement it.

Comment: did you try `man chmod` ? or simply google: [*chmod*](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

Comment: @alfasin : No i have not ....wait i will try

Comment: These commands are absolutely the wrong solution. The proper solution is to use `sudo` for the operations which require administrator privileges. If you don't have `sudo` access, obtain it.

Comment: @tripleee : I am learning commands as I am going in deeper with ubuntu ..found it amazing to use !!! have started looking in to help documentation of ubuntu... hope i will make it soon

Answer (score 9):

The positions about numbers is in this way:

- first  position -> permisions for the  Owner  (current user)
- second  position -> permisions for the  Group  (set by owner)
- third  position -> permisions for  anyone else

So the numbers means:

0 – no permission, this person cannot read, write or execute
1 – execute only
2 – write only
3 – execute and write only (1 + 2)
4 – read only
5 – execute and read only (1 + 4)
6 – write and read only (2 + 4)
7 – execute, write and read (1 + 2 + 4)

For example:

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/
```

Owner -> can execute, write and read
Current user -> can execute and read only
Anyone else -> can execute and read only